# How can I understand instantons as sheaves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, mathematical-physics, coherent-sheaves, moduli-space

In specific, instantons are considered torsion free coherent sheaves. Why is that the case? Is there a nice way to understand this relation and of course also understand how the two moduli spaces (instantons and torsion free coherent sheaves) are identified?

Comment: Crossposted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/218099/2451